# How can I run specific feature in nightwatch.js with cucumber integration

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am new to nightwatch.js with cucumber integration. I have kept all my different feature files in tests/features folder and all corresponding step definition js files in tests/features/step_definitions folder.
for example my tests/features folder contains usecase1.feature and usecase2.feature and my step definition folder tests/features/step_definitions has usecase1.js and usecase2.js files. I want to run only specific use case for example usecase1 which should ideally run scenarios covered only in usecase1.feature file. Can someone help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think better way of doing it is by the use of tags. You can tag your specific scenarios using tags in your feature file and then you can invoke Nightwatch-cucumber for that particular tag. Nightwatch-cucumber will execute all use cases for that particular tag.

Here is the sample for your reference:

**scenario.feature**

```
Feature: Test Feature

  @Tag1
  Scenario: Sample Test 1
   Given ...
   When ...
   Then ...

  @Tag2
  Scenario: Sample Test 2
   Given ...
   When ...
   Then ...
```

Add below parameter to command at the time of invoking nightwatch

```
    --tag  Tag1
```

This will execute all the test scenarios with tag Tag1. This should solve your problem.